# What's the difference between setOnClickListener() & setOnCheckedChangedListener() for checkbox?

Tags: android

**What's the difference between setOnClickListener() & setOnCheckedChangedListener() for checkbox?**

I am working with both listener but i could not find any difference,they both gives same answer.Please solve this query

thank you

regards

Ayudh

Answer (score 0):

We use `setOnClickListener()` for Perform action on clicks, depending on whether it's now checked or not whereas `setOnCheckedChangedListener()`  method used for checkbox change listener -- that is where  we handle the changes in the checkbox state.

Answer (score 0):

**setOnClickListener()** is a listener that can be used mostly with all kinds of  view(widgets) for performing action on Click while **setOnCheckedChangedListener()** is used only to change the state of checkbox and radio buttons. You should prefer **setOnCheckedChangedListener()** for changing the state of checkbox and perform some action.

Answer (score 0):

Google uses onClickListener in [this tutorial](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-formstuff.html), even when they manipulate widgets that support the change listener.